# Browser-sync + npm not working properly

Tags: npm, browser-sync

i have a problem with my browsersync using npm. When i want to start browsersync it shows "listing directory /" instead of my index.html. When i click index.html it shows Cannot GET /index.html. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found one fix and it's working for me so I will post a solution here for anyone who will have same problem :)

So it's simple, I've had in my package.json script:

```
    "watch:browsersync": "browser-sync start --server --files \"css/*.css\" \"*.html\" --serveStatic \"./\""
```

And to fix my problem I've added last one :

```
 --serveStatic \"./\""
```

And it fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
browser-sync --cwd
```

This seems to be the correct command. "cwd" stands for current working directory. I am using the version 2.26.7

It seems you need to run the command `browser-sync start` Then you need to stop the process and then use the cwd command.